# D3 Pie chart arc is invisible in transition to 180°

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've a pie chart build with d3 and svg. I use transitions on the `d` attribute of the svg path to animate changes in the pie chart. Is works as expected except when the target size of the arc is >=180°. Then the arc path is invisible during the transition.

Demonstration: http://jsbin.com/EXeXUXE/4/edit

I think this is because d3 produces invalid path information during the transition:

```
Error: Problem parsing d="M1.4082973068957338e-14,-230A230,230 0 0.0000013720000000000002,1 135.1904225457546,186.07396897283516L0,0Z"
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug and is there a way to work arround?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use the normal transition/tween to animate radial charts, you need a custom tween function -- this has been covered numerous times for pie charts, see e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410).

Comment: @Lars, thanks. Its logical that its not producing a nice rotation animation, but why is it producing illigal paths instead of an non optimal transition?

Comment: I'll add an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that `d3.svg.arc()` uses the `A` SVG path command to draw the elliptical arc. The format of that command is as follows.

```
A (rx ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag sweep-flag x y)+
```

The meaning of the individual parameters is not important, the only thing relevant here are `large-arc-flag` and `sweep-flag`. According to the [SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html)

> - Of the four candidate arc sweeps, two will represent an arc sweep of greater than or equal to 180 degrees (the "large-arc"), and two will represent an arc sweep of less than or equal to 180 degrees (the "small-arc"). If large-arc-flag is '1', then one of the two larger arc sweeps will be chosen; otherwise, if large-arc-flag is '0', one of the smaller arc sweeps will be chosen,
> - If sweep-flag is '1', then the arc will be drawn in a "positive-angle" direction (i.e., the ellipse formula x=cx+rx*cos(theta) and y=cy+ry*sin(theta) is evaluated such that theta starts at an angle corresponding to the current point and increases positively until the arc reaches (x,y)). A value of 0 causes the arc to be drawn in a "negative-angle" direction (i.e., theta starts at an angle value corresponding to the current point and decreases until the arc reaches (x,y)).

As their names suggest, these are flags, i.e. 0/1 values. This is what `d3.svg.arc()` generates. However when you interpolate between them using `.transition()` with the default path tween, D3 interprets them as numerical values and not as flags. The means that intermediate paths will have values between 0 and 1 for these flags, which are illegal. It is because of that that the parsing fails.

To fix, use a custom tween (which you need to use for radial paths anyway). See e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) for an example that shows you how to do it.