# D3.js "Invalid value for <path> attribute..." yet chart still updates

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm rolling through Mike Bostock's unbelievable collection of examples, and I am currently trying to get my own version of Pie Update II working (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410). I've co-mingled with code shown here (http://jonsadka.com/blog/how-to-create-adaptive-pie-charts-with-transitions-in-d3/) to help me better understand what's actually going on. By this, I mean I've been tweaking the mbostock example by individually adding bits of code from the other example to see what works and what doesn't.

Regardless, I have a simple HTML page set up with radio buttons declared like so:

```
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" name="dataset" value="photoCounts2" checked> Photos</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="dataset" value="videoCounts2"> Videos</label>
</form>
```

I have an array of integers of equal size (10), named `videoCounts2` and `photoCounts2`. I'm trying to be able to click on a radio button and have the pie chart adjust to the corresponding dataset. I don't require a smooth transition just yet, I'd first like to get the initial transition working. Here is the JavaScript:

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
// Global vars
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */   
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
// Data Agnostic - Setup page elements
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */       
var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d) { return d; })
  .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 100)
  .outerRadius(radius - 20);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
// Data Dependent
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */       
var path = g.datum(photoCounts2).selectAll("path")
    .data(pie)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial angles

d3.selectAll("input")
    .on("change", change);

function change() {
    console.log("made it to change");
    data = ((this.value === "photoCounts2") ? photoCounts2 : videoCounts2); // This needs to be changed if the dataset is different than video count.
    console.log(this.value);
    // Transition the pie chart
    g.datum(data).selectAll("path")
        .data(pie)
        .transition()
        .attr("d", arc);

    // Add any new data
    g.datum(data).selectAll("path")
        .data(pie)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial angles

    // Remove any unused data
    g.datum(data).selectAll("path")
        .data(pie)
        .exit()
        .remove();
}
```

I actually get the desired functionality, and nothing *visually* breaks, but I continually get the following error printed to the console when I switch between datasets (by choosing a different radio input):

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M1.4083438190194563e-14,-230A230,230 0 0.000006912,1 217.6110300447649,-74.45790482200897L141.92023698571626,-48.559503144788465A150,150 0 0.000006912,0 9.184850993605149e-15,-150Z"
(anonymous function) @ d3.js:8717
tick @ d3.js:8914
(anonymous function) @ d3.js:8906
d3_timer_mark @ d3.js:2159
d3_timer_step @ d3.js:2139
```

I truly believe I've done my due diligence looking elsewhere for solutions, but I'm stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've found that if I comment out `.transition()` from my `change()` function, the errors disappear and the charts update as intended, but without the default transitioning animation. Could these errors be from d3 trying to dynamically update path values during the transition phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the error because some of the intermediate `d` values for the `path`s that are generated by the transition are invalid. As each of these is only visible for a few milliseconds, you don't actually see the error.

The root cause of the problem is that D3's default transition can't interpolate pie chart segments correctly. To make it work properly, you need to use a custom attribute tween, e.g. as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410):

```
path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween);
function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}
```

This tells D3 how to generate all the intermediate values; in this case, by interpolating the angle of the segment and using the arc generator to generate the path for the changed angle (as opposed to interpolating the path itself without knowledge on how it was generated in the first place).

Comment: I feel so dumb now.. I read over this post too quickly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285385/d3-pie-chart-arc-is-invisible-in-transition-to-180%C2%B0

Comment: Thanks Lars that was a great explanation!